# Edit the Html.BeginForm helper method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a specific theme which I apply to my html and now instead of editing it everything I create view. I want to edit the html helper methods and all all my necessary classes and id information can be put in one place.

How do i do this?

Do I just create a new custom one or is it easier to edit one that is already there? I do plan to add some ones that are not there.

I have googled abit but all the answerers I found give specific code to their problem. I dont even know which folder to put my classes in? In a book im reading about mvc it explains custom model template, but i dont think that is exactly what im looking for?

Even a basic example will be great.

Comment: Your description is a bit broad for my taste. I can however say that I am using custom templates and just redirect all the rendering to them using, for example the `Editor` helper. It's simple and straightforward. I can't really say I'm not pleased and that I would create additional helpers.

Comment: So what is the difference between a custom template and a custom heplper?

Comment: For one, I find it much more convenient to structure and style the elements using HTML and Razor than using a string builder. In my custom view I can also take full advantage of the model metadata and take actions accordingly (e.g. add additional info to the elements). Testing works great to. I don't need to stop debugging or to compile my code; I just hit refresh in the browser. At the end, it's a mater of preference. For me, this works best.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I just create a new custom one or is it easier to edit one that is
>   already there? I do plan to add some ones that are not there.

I would say creating a custom one would be fast and simple. But if you still want to give a try by enhancing existing one, than you can get the source code of [System.Web.Mvc for CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/Html/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs), and make your necessary modifications and build it, reference it and use it in your project.